# Assigning spatial info for NetCDF files using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, netcdf, ascii

I have quite a few NetCDF files that arrive from a air quality model without any spatial reference.  However, I do have the spatial reference information that is required.

- Within Arc I use "make a netcdf raster layer", it has "undefined" spatial info in properties.
- Within the undefined netcdf properties I can view several of the chemical variables like NH3, C02, etc in the drop down menu.

[image]

- Defining the projection does not change the spatial info and returns the same "undefined"

I have been able to assign a spatial reference by converting that layer to ASCII and then creating a prj and manually adding the spatial info needed to the files.  This creates a chemical layer that is spatially correct...
However this process does not keep the several chemicals in the netcdf drop down mentioned earlier but only one chemical...and this is a slow process.

Is there an easier way to go about this instead of  displaying in Netcdf in arc as raster, then converting to ASCII and then manually adding in spatial info?  And still be able to keep all the variables in the drop down menu in the Netcdf tab?

Answer (score 1):

I know you say an easier way in ARC but an easier way does exist. You can go directly from NetCDF to virtually any format and batch the process to get each "attribute" you need using the subdataset command in [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) (use OSGEO4W version). [This](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html) would be your start point.